# Display function in header.tpl - Prestashop

Tags: function, prestashop

I would like to say that i am quite new to prestashop.

I have added FrontController.php to override/classes/controller.
The file contains the following code

```
class FrontControllerCore extends Controller
{

public function thefunct()
{
    return 'AA';
}

}
```

Now in the header.tpl i try to call the function by using {FrontController::thefunct()}.

When I put the public function in classes/controller it works, but when I put it in the override folder it doesn't.

How do I display the function in my header.tpl?
And how does the override folder work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you use ps 1.5)

If you are overriding `FrontController` you need to initiate your class like so

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
```

and delete `cache/class_index.php` file, (I mean, delete it everytime you override new controller or class)

Teach yourself [`how to override in ps`](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors). through excellent docs.

**EDIT:**

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {

    //here you should create and assign variables which you want to use in templates
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        //in such a way you assign variables into smarty template
        $this->context->smarty->assign(
            array(
                'acme_variable' => $this->acme()
            )
        );
    }

    protected function acme()
    {
        return "Wile E. Coyote and The Road Runner";
    }
}


//header.tpl

<div>{$acme_variable}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, im using 1.5.4 But when i follow ur instructions I still just get a blank webpage.

Do you know if {FrontController::thefunct()} is the correct way of calling the function in the .tpl file?

Comment: Check my edit, I would advise you not to use stuff like `{FrontController::thefunct()}` in templates, rather create your content in a controller's method, assign it to a variable and use it in your template. If you do not get it, either follow my code or study manual of overriding behaviour which I provided by link to official documentation

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ah Yes, well i've consulted the manual for overriding before posting my question but it all was rather confusing to me. However, your answer fortunately makes way more sense to me. Thanks m8!